# Limit children/nesting type with HTMLPurifier

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

How would I configure HTMLPurifier to prevent elements from having certain children? (or even another php solution would work)

For example I would like to prevent things like the following:

```
<p><p>text</p></p>
<ul><li><ul><li>text</li></ul></li></ul>
```

and would like them to convert to

```
<p>text</p>
<ul><li>text<li></ul>
```

I have looked up the documentation and found that EscapeInvalidChildren is depreciated. Are there any new alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `excludes` attribute on the relevant `HTMLPurifier_ElementDef`. You'll have to use the http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html hands on the necessary objects.

Comment: Thanks! I'll read up on the ElementDef doc. Would you be able to post an example of how to set the excludes on an element?